# How to display an image for each row of a multi-line text?

Tags: css

Consider a `<div>` element containing a variable amount of elements of various heights which can cover several rows. Is there a way to display a particular image for each row of this text?
[See this example](https://jsfiddle.net/brunoperel/x07z2cvo/) :

HTML:

```
<div id="bookcase">
  <div class="shelf">

  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var bookNumber = 300;
for (var i =0; i<bookNumber;i++) {
    $('#bookcase').prepend($('<span>').css({
    width: (5+20*Math.random()*Math.random()) + 'px',
    height: (300*Math.random()*Math.random()) + 'px'
  }).addClass('book'));
}
```

CSS:

```
.book {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.shelf {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url("http://sr.photos3.fotosearch.com/bthumb/CSP/CSP994/k15715591.jpg");
}
```

The goal is to show a shelf for each row of books. To make the code easy to read, the book elements are generated through JS, but I would prefer not to use JS to create the shelf elements and use CSS only.

What I tried:

- When generating the book elements, create a `<div>` child for each row, containing a set of books + the shelf image at the end of it : it doesn't work because I need to know how many books each row will have (since I want the bookcase to take all the page width) and I don't know that in advance.
- `background-repeat` property with the shelf image repeating vertically: it doesn't work because I don't know in advance what height each of the row will be.
- JavaScript solution where I detect when a row can't hold more books, and add a shelf image at this point : that will be my last resort : I would like a pure-CSS solution.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: After looking at your code,i would assume that the spans are the books, now i would suggest that in your js, you create a `div.row` fill it with those books aka spans then push the the row to the `div.shelf` you can calculate how many span you can add using the documents width with that you're able to add a background to each `div.row`

Comment: Can you please add your code directly to the question? That way, if the jsfiddle ever becomes unavailable, someone in the future can still understand your question.

Comment: @ecg8 Thanks, done that

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it configured right now obviously won't work. This is because you currently have no way of dividing your books on the page. In this sense you only have one shelf.

```
<div class="bookCase">
<span class="book">
.
.
.
<div class="shelf"></div>
</div>
```

You can add a thick bottom border (20px or so) to each book to make a sort of pseudo shelf like so.

```js
var bookNumber = 300;

for (var i =0; i<bookNumber;i++) {
 $('#bookcase').prepend($('<span>').css({
   width: (5+20*Math.random()*Math.random()) + 'px',
   height: (300*Math.random()*Math.random()) + 'px'
  }).addClass('book'));
}
```

```css
.book {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 20px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bookcase"></div>
```

Personally, I would go with your last resort and add a "resize" listener to the window to dynamically re-build your shelf if the containing element changes sizes.

Comment: Thank you. Applying your advice of a border under each book and fiddling a bit with border-image I can produce a decent effect (https://jsfiddle.net/brunoperel/5rrmL1bp/), however since the background is repeated for each book it doesn't create a great shelf rendering altogether